# Reopening a game fullscreen is being broken in pygame

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame, fullscreen, fullscreenchange

I am trying to make a 700x700 fullscreen game in pygame, but whenever I get out of the game and get back in, the screen breaks, showing what was opened before reopening the game. How do I fix it without changing the width and height of the screen?

```
Width, Height = 700, 700
win = pygame.display.set_mode((Width, Height), pygame.FULLSCREEN)
```

Comment: Are you using hardware acceleration?

Comment: what is hardware acceleration?

Comment: Do you mean that I change the screen based on the resolution of the player's screen?

Comment: Are you using `pygame.HWSURFACE` or `pygame.DOUBLEBUFF`, because either of these options will prevent the screen from automatically refreshing when minimized, forcing you to do that manually

Comment: Also, please post your code. We can't spot problems in your code if you don't post it

Comment: I've put the code just now

Comment: So what exactly is the unwanted side effect?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/216424/discussion-between-abdullah-alawad-and-mousetail).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have to reset the fullscreen modifier whenever your window gets activated again. This might be a bug in a new version of pygame.

You can detect when the game gets maximized with `pygame.ACTIVEEVENT`. You can put something like this in your event loop:

```
if event.type == pygame.ACTIVEEVENT:
    if event.gain == 1:
        win = pygame.display.set_mode((Width, Height), pygame.FULLSCREEN)
```